# Kendo Jquery Grid Auto Fit Column Horizontal Scroller Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a Kendo Jquery grid, and there are some numbers of columns. I use autofit inside the databound to fit those columns, so I have a problem when I hit the sort or filter in the final column. It automatically scrolls horizontally to the left; I want to avoid that, and I want to stay in the filter or sorting column without autoscrolling.

I try setting up the fixed column width, then it works correctly, but in my scenario, I have to go with the autofit columns, so I want to figure it out.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.